# How do i validate a textfield on button click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use jQuery to validate if a textbox is not empty and consists of digits, when i click on a button?

This is the code i have so far:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="Tilføj" value="Tilføj" id="add" />
<input type="text" id="element" name="element" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#add").click(function () {

        $("#element").validate({
            rules: {
                element: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                }
            },
            errorHandler: function () {
                $("#result").append("error");
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                $("#result").append("good");
            }

        });

    });
});
```

Do i have to use jQuery validation inside a form for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a jQuery plugin. All you need is a simple Regular expression to validate your input format. You can customize it for different type of inputs

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

function validate_input( inputText)
    {
        if( inputText.length > 0 )
        {
            // Search for non-digit pattern (\D) globally
            var patt=/\D/g ;

            if( patt.test( inputText ) )
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

$(document).ready(function () 
{      
    $("#add").click(function () 
    {

        if( validate_input( $("#element").val() ) )
        {
            $("#result").html("<label> good </label>");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("<label> error </label>");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This works very good and i can use it without forms and AJAX. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

```
//AJAX way to submit the form

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post( {
       url: $(this).attr("action"), 
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(){ 

           //Write code here to handle on success 

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey :) Can you point me to where i my code is wrong, and also where i shoud look in the validation documentation?

Comment: You need to use validate on a form element. Rest jquery willl take care.

Comment: After the validation, i have to add some dynamic content to a form using Javascript. When i submit a form, the page refreshes and the dynamic content is lost. Do you have an example on how to get around this? I guess i'd have to use Ajax

Comment: Yes you have to use ajax for this

Comment: @Nanek - Check my edited answer I have shown how to submit the form using ajax, hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without jQuery using `<input type="number" id="element" name="element" required />` and the full code being:

```
<form>
  <input type="number" id="element" name="element" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that not all browsers supports the `number` type for input elements.

Comment: This is very true. I wanted to offer another solution instead of instantly turning to jQuery. ShankarSangoli has the jQuery bit covered more or less.

Comment: Does this check if the value is a digit? Which is necessary for me. Also, how do i call a javascript function when i submit this form?

Comment: It will check if they're numbers and not allow submission if they aren't. As for calling the function, I believe it would be on the `type="submit"` click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            element: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        errorHandler: function () {
            $("#result").append("error");
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            $("#result").append("good");
        }

    });

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('form').validate();
    });
});
```